# How to change language of the Save Parts dialog in eclipse e4 rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

On closing a dirty part I get a *Save Parts* dialog. But there is appearently no way to change its header or the text "Select the parts to save:" message. My application is running with parameter `-nl de` so I expect this text to be in German, but this is not the case. Does anyone know how to localize this dialog?

Comment: It is also possible to replace the dialog by using a custom implementation of `ISaveHandler`.

Comment: Is there a typo in `-ln de` or do you actually use this form? The correct argument to use the _German_ locale would be `-nl de`.

Comment: @Rüdiger Herrmann thanks for the correction, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

For changing langage of default eclipse plugin, you need to install a plug-in like [Babel](https://www.eclipse.org/babel/downloads.php) (add your langage only: German) and add it to your product.

There is a German fragment for every Eclipse plug-in providing translation.

Comment: the babel plugin for German is already added, but the problem is not resolved.